# Angular CLI Error path and code EEXIST

Tags: angular, command-line-interface, angular-cli

I first installed npm and made sure it was up to date.
Then I tried installing angular but I was faced with errors

```
~ kode$ sudo npm install -g @angular/cli

Password:

npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.1.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! path /usr/local/bin/ng

npm ERR! code EEXIST

npm ERR! Refusing to delete /usr/local/bin/ng: ../lib/node_modules/angular-cli/bin/ng symlink target is not controlled by npm /usr/local/bin

npm ERR! File exists: /usr/local/bin/ng

npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.


npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     /Users/kode/.npm/_logs/2018-02-15T13_10_57_836Z-debug.log
```

I don't understand how it tells me that the file already exists yet when I run any ng command it tells me:

```
ng: command not found
```

I'm fairly new to node and angular all together so here's what I tried:

I tried uninstalling angular: `sudo npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`

Then reinstalling it: `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli`

And it didn't work of course.

If you do know how to solve this please help a beginner out, thank you.

Answer (score 39):

You need to delete ng folder from `/usr/local/bin`:

```
 sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/ng
```

Then retry the installation:

```
 sudo npm i -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: It is `@angular/cli `, not `angular/cli`.

Comment: Please mind the right path of "ng" folder. It could be different, such as `/usr/bin/ng`.

Comment: In my case I had to remove /usr/bin/ng

Comment: it works thanks but  for me the path was /usr/bin/ng

Comment: sudo npm doesn't exist for me

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue as you but I found that if I went to the /usr/local/bin folder and erased the ng file then reinstalled angular it worked.

If you already tried to install angular follow this the uninstall directions here https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-1.0-update, then erase the ng file then reinstall.