# NPM fails to install @angular/cli saying "File already exists"

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I want to install `@angular/cli` but it doesn't work, I have reinstalled Node but the problem persists.

[image]

Text output:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-MAC:~ macayoub$ npm -v
6.14.4
MacBook-Pro-de-MAC:~ macayoub$ node -v
v12.16.2
MacBook-Pro-de-MAC:~ macayoub$ sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
Password:
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
npm ERR! dest /Users/macayoub/.npm-global/bin/ng
npm ERR! errno -17
npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, symlink '../lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng' -> '/Users/macayoub/.npm-global/bin/ng'
npm ERR! File exists: /Users/macayoub/.npm-global/bin/ng
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/macayoub/.npm/_logs/2020-04-21T08_23_36_422Z-debug.log
```

Comment: The error message directly says what to do: *"Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm with --force to overwrite files recklessly."*. Have you tried doing any of these two solutions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular CLI Error path and code EEXIST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48808384/angular-cli-error-path-and-code-eexist)

Answer (score 2):

You need to delete ng folder from /usr/local/bin
Install again

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/ng 
sudo npm i -g @angular/cli
```

Find out a duplicate question at [Angular CLI Error path and code EEXIST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48808384/angular-cli-error-path-and-code-eexist)

and answer at:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52621562/165260

Please also avoid posting duplicate questions, first search them on community.
Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

Try to do a clean install and not use sudo with NPM. There are some blogs about this topic:

- https://medium.com/@ExplosionPills/dont-use-sudo-with-npm-still-66e609f5f92

Comment: This can't be stressed enough: `sudo npm` gives total control of your computer to non-vetted, non-audited, user created scripts, that can potentially do something harmful to it, either by malice or incompetence.

If you're not changing something on the computer itself, don't use `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

If similar issue faced on windows then below option to be performed:

1. Navigate to path C:\Users\AppData\Roaming which is default directory for installation
2. Delete npm and npm-cache folder
3. Re-attempt with command "npm install -g @angular/cli" and this time it should work

[image]