# Angular CLI Installetion Error for Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: javascript, angular

```
sudo npm install -global @angular/cli
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
npm ERR! dest /usr/bin/ng
npm ERR! errno -17
npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, symlink '../lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng' -> '/usr/bin/ng'
npm ERR! File exists: /usr/bin/ng
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-10-03T08_55_44_693Z-debug.log
```

Comment: I am already install Node.js or NPM in my system

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular CLI Error path and code EEXIST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48808384/angular-cli-error-path-and-code-eexist)

Answer (score 0):

I also use Ubuntu 20.04 and I just had the same problem as you.

Here I just updated the npm package (via synaptic).

After this, `sudo npm i -g @angular/cli` worked ok.

This point solved my problem, maybe that can help you too.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on Ubuntu 20.04, after I install nodejs (in my case 14.17 stable) and try install Angular. 
I went to the directory *`/usr/bin`* and deleted the `ng` file,
after `sudo npm i -g @angular/cli`. 
So `ng --version` to see if installed ok.
I hope help yo, bye.